# Convergence of sequences of RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X,X_n,n\geq 1$ be random variables, and $\epsilon_n >0$. Suppose that:
$\sum_{n \geq 1} P(|X_n-X|\geq \epsilon_n)<\infty$

Show that: $X_n \overset{a.s}{\rightarrow}X$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$ when $\epsilon_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Worth reading about the [Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)

Answer (score 1):

Denote the sequence of events $(A_n)_n$ as $A_n:=\{|X_n-X|\ge\epsilon_n\}$.

Since we have a *convergent series* of probability of events,
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} P(|X_n-X|\geq \epsilon_n) = \sum_{n \geq 1} P(A_n) < +\infty
$$
it's natural to apply Borel-Cantelli lemma to deduce that $P(\limsup_n A_n)=0$, where
$$
\limsup_n A_n := \bigcap_{n\ge1} \bigcup_{k\ge n} A_k
= \bigcap_{n\ge1} \bigcup_{k\ge n} \{|X_k-X|\ge\epsilon_k\}.
$$
Thus, the event $(\limsup_n A_n)^C$ is realized almost surely.
$$
\mathrm{a.s.}\quad \exists {n\ge1}, \forall {k\ge n}, |X_k-X| < \epsilon_k
$$
Take $k\to\infty$ and make use of $\epsilon_k \to 0$ to conclude that
$$
\mathrm{a.s.}\quad \lim_{k\to\infty} |X_k - X| = 0.
$$